# SQL: Generate primary key value that is NOT auto generated and has data type of char/nchar

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, primary-key

I want to enter some data into a table using asp.net web form. I am not giving user UI to enter value for primary key column required in the table, where data goes into. The table has primary key column (char) that does not generate values automatically.

How can i go about generating unique values every time user fills out the form?

How can I perform a check that it is indeed unique when entering the data second time?

Thanks

Comment: I must say this is a very bad practice. Database is the best & easiest place to generate keys.

Comment: Use a sequence, retrieve the next value, then convert that to the character value you want (could be done in a function).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, could you elaborate with some code please? thanks

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: **why** isn't the key column generated automatically? What requirements must the values fulfill which can not be fulfilled by an auto-increment field? Knowing this is important to give you advice on how to auto-generate unique values.

Comment: @krshekhar, MS SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Have you rights to edit this table PK to change its type or length?

Comment: @Philipp, this is what I would argue, but I cannot change the db behaviour at this point

Comment: @user1889838: SQL Server 2008 R2 does not support sequences (they were introduced with SQL Server 2012), so my suggestion won't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your SQL that will fulfill this task.
This is not what should be done as the comments says, but try using the GUID() function in sql to generate a unique key, then take the 20 characters from it...

Without testing, it will looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GenerateKey
()
RETURNS CHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @test CHAR (36) 

-- NEWID() will generate a 36 character unique key.
SET @test = NEWID()

-- take the 20 first
SET @test = SUBSTRING(NEWID(),1,20)

--compare @test to the keys already existings to check if you can use it

--Then return @test as the new Key

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different datetime format for creating unique key.
Datetime will be never repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want DateTime to be used a simple way is use Random function of Java to generate Random numbers and store it as primary key.To check if the random number has not been repeated compare the number with all the random numbers that have been stored in your table as primary key.